# Скачать файл по ссылке и предоставить выбор места его сохранения

Tags: java

У меня есть свой сайт, на нем лежит `zip` файл. Я хочу сделать, чтобы пользователь в программе (Java) нажимал кнопку и этот файл скачивался, затем пользователь выбирал место сохранения.

Comment: На чем сделан сайт? JSP?

Comment: html и javascript

Comment: Тогда где кнопка? В приложении типа desktop? То есть есть некий клиент для вашего сайта?

Comment: да, в программе Desktop

Comment: На чем сделан клиент(Swing, JavaFX пр.)?

Comment: полностью на Swing

Comment: Типа такого? http://www.codejava.net/coding/swing-application-to-download-files-from-http-server-with-progress-bar

Comment: я писал через windowbuilder для Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам понадобится прямая ссылка на ваш файл на сервере. Вот пример создания диалога и сохранения файла

```
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("myfile.txt"));
    if (JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION == fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null)) {
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt").openStream());
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = bis.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                fos.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //TODO: log
        } finally {
            if (bis != null) {
                try {
                    bis.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //TODO: log
                }
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //TODO: log
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: все работает, спасибо

Comment: не за что. Тогда отметьте ответ как верный(галочку нажмите)